# Why gstreamer GST-LAUNCH buffering frequently while running?

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

Im running a simple command on Ubuntu 18.04 release.

`gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm`

This command opens a example video window. But while running, video stops and buffer then continue repeatedly about 2 seconds.

Here is the output of terminal;

````
user@user:~$ gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'source': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
Redistribute latency...
Prerolled, waiting for buffering to finish...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstPulseSinkClock
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Buffering, setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Done buffering, setting pipeline to PLAYING ...```

What may cause this problem? 

Thanks,
M.Altay
````